# How to Convert a .CPP file to .bin ?

Tags: c++, qt, centos7, bin

I did a QT project in windows 10. But it needs to run in Linux CentOS. They asked me to send the bin file to them. But I don't know how to convert cpp to bin. I googled and in a website it was written that only renaming to bin would be enough. I tried to rename '.cpp' extension to '.bin'. But it doesn't work. Is there any tools to do this?

Comment: cross compile or compile it on centos.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the instructions. What is expected from you is to provide a compiled version of your program that can run on CentOS. 
A compiled program is often referred to as a `binary`.

For QT, it seems possible to compile on Windows for CentOS: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#cross-compilation-options